# Automating test cases for COBOL programs

Tags: automated-testing

Now I am trying with a Java library called tn5250j, which provides scripting capabilities, but it is not well documented and I didn't find much on the Internet.

Does anyone have experience with this library, or with any other tool in order to automate test cases for a COBOL program, running on an iSeries/AS400 server?

Comment: No experience but I see https://github.com/gbeine/COBOLUnit

Comment: Hi, thank you! 
It's a different approach. You need to program Cobol and test the Cobol methods. I want to test the system as a black box, actually, I don't have any access to the source code.

Comment: The only times I made that, I mad a custom tool specific to my needs. In COBOL.

Comment: What's your actual question? Does anyone have experience? The answer is yes. Does that solve your question? No. Please rephrase it to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned black box testing and given that I would consider a different language / framework for the testing.

For example I recently was writing a bunch of bash programs and wrote my own test runner in bash.

Basically, to get started you run the program / module and then you examine the results in comparison to what you expect.  So the test runner does that, it runs the programs and examine the output and can pass/fail depending on whether it is correct.

Comment: @FedericoToledo - could you upvote the answer and accept it, if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expirienced in COBOL so also not in testing it but here are some links I found on google. If they are useful I can't evaluate. (*@All: But as this text is too long for comment I put it as an answer.*)

- [Presentation: zUnit  - A journey into unit testing COBOL and PLI applications](http://www.gse-nordic.org/2013/S604%20-%20What%20is%20zUnit%20-%20A%20journey%20into%20unit%20testing.pdf)
- [COBOLUnit](https://sites.google.com/site/cobolunit/about)
- [Post about COBOL automating tools](http://support.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=151)
- [Presentation about silktest which should be for automating COBOL](https://www.microfocus.com/assets/9-functional-testing-of-cobol_tcm6-203958.pdf)

This shows you what you've tested but won't automate it:

- [COBOL Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/COBOLTestCoverage.html)

Comment: Thank you bish! I've already googled it and see the same info, but not what I'm looking for (commertial, different approaches). 
Thank you anyway. Hope to find someone with experience and some references on that